# Is there a way to trigger a callback on a Rails model only after a commit has happened for a create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, callback, rails-activerecord

I am calling a "queue" method from the `after_create` callback to trigger a Sidekiq process on a model instance after it is created. However, the first time my Sidekiq worker picks up the job, the record hasn't been committed yet.

I know there is an `after_commit` record, but I only want the object queued when it was created, not when it is updated. How can I accomplish this without any hackery involving date-checking, etc.?

Comment: Introduce a sleep? That might work too ( a hack again ).

Comment: It would at least reduce the failures.

Comment: how about checking `#id_was` in `after_commit` method. If it was a new record perhaps it should be `nil`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a flag in `before_create` callback

```rb
before_create :set_new_flag
after_commit :queue

def set_new_flag
  @__new_flag = true
end

def queue
  if defined? @__new_flag
    #queue it up
    remove_instance_variable(:@__new_flag)
  end
  # puts self.previous_changes
end
```

Or just inspect `#previous_changes` in the `after_commit`. The `nil` in id key should only be for new_records. Here's an example output of `previous_changes`

```rb
{"name"=>[nil, "newest"], "id"=>[nil, "cBdjzQgxir45xQJ9UXGRSR"], "version_id"=>[nil, "cBdnAogxir45xQJ9UXGRSR"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct method is to use the `:on` option:

```
after_commit :queue, :on => :create
```

More here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html#method-i-after_commit

Comment: This looks like the way to go. Can anyone confirm this does the trick?

Comment: @JoshPinter Works for me! I've used it in several codebases where sidekiq was picking up job IDs that had not yet been committed to the database.